# Sass :: Radio button design

Tags: html, css, sass, radio-button

We have specific requirement to design a radio button as displayed below.

[image]

I have tried material design radio button. But it doesn't have inner circle.

Can some one please help design a radio button like above in Sass/CSS.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: My Application is not an angular js application which is built in jquery. I tried to design a material radio button by just extracting the css of material radio button design and done some tweeks. But I am not able to create a inner circle.

Comment: Angular? well, check my answer and let me know if it helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you a hint, you will just have to apply the right look to your "fake radio".

The idea is to have and input[type=radio] with opacity 0 and display the next element with the unchecked style. then use `input:checked + <element>` to apply the the checked styles

You need a markup like so:

```css
.pretty-radio {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.radio {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.radio-look {  
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.radio-look:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.radio:checked + .radio-look:after {
    background: blue; // or any other style you need
}
```

```html
<div class="pretty-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="my-radio">
    <span class="radio-look"></span>
    Radio text
</div>
<div class="pretty-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="my-radio">
    <span class="radio-look"></span>
    Radio text 2
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But I need an another circle inside it if the radio button is not selected. Just like as shown in the image (Radio Button 1). That is where I stuck.

Comment: check my edit, you can use an absolute pseudo element :after or :before ( i'll let you just play with the colors )